# "I have" followed by "have" instead of "need"

Tags: grammar

Is it okay to use "**I have**" 2 times in the same sentence in this case?

> I have a class I have to teach.
>
> I have a meeting I have to attend.
>
> I have a book I have  to read.

To me it would sound much better if I added "**need**" instead of "**have**" to the end of the sentence, but just out of curiosity. Is this okay grammaticality? And if not, why?

Comment: Have you considered the shorter versions of 1 and 2: "I have a class to teach" and "I have a meeting to attend"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences are grammatical and idiomatic.

"Have to" is a phrasal verb having the same meaning as the modal "must." If you do not recognize that equivalence instantaneously, you will have difficulty parsing the sentence, particularly because a relative pronoun is implied rather than stated.

> I have a class I have to teach
>
> I have a class that I have to teach
>
> I have a class I must teach
>
> I have a class that I must teach

All mean the same thing.

It is true that many would use "need," but that sometimes has a slightly different meaning than "have to."